# Why am I getting IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_userprofile.email
```

The field looks like this:

```
email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default=None)
```

I do not understand. Error happens when creating instance of the model and not setting the email field. But it's blank and it's charfield, and None if not overwritten, why is it happening?

Comment: set null=True in your field

Comment: @mohammad got it, but why charfield requires null=True when it can be blank and there is a default value?

Comment: I think by default django when creates model fields it makes them NOT NULL in database. So settings default = None with NOT NULL is a Inconsistency

Comment: Also note that when you set null=True, then default=None is not required any more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two option:

1. set `null = True` which is used if you want to save null value in Database.
2. set `blank = True` which is used for form validation. You can call save form without value in that field.

In your current issue you just have to add `null = True`.

```
email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

[As noted here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#null), using null=True in charField and TextField should be avoided. Because then your field has two options for no data. one is None another is blank string.

By the way null is by default set to False in django fields and you should set it to True in your case.

Comment: Why are we using it if it is to be avoided?